# Moved an IntelliJ project from Windows desktop to Linux Mint laptop, now class-type variables are of wrong type

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, linux-mint

I've recently set up an older laptop with Linux Mint to use for my programming class. So to test around a bit, I moved a project from my main desktop (running Windows) to my laptop. However, on the Linux Mint laptop, IntelliJ is telling me that some of my variables of a certain selfmade-class-type are of the wrong type.

A picture of my class structure (this will be important in a bit):
[image: class structure]

I have a class `Internal()` and a class `View(Internal internal, String windowName)`. As you can see, to create a `View` object, one needs an `Internal` object first. This is implemented like so:

```
// starts the program/application
public static void main (String[] args) {

    Internal i = new Internal();
    View gui = new View(i, "Husky :D");

}
```

Now, here IntelliJ said that the variable `i` is of the type `Internal` but should be of type `program.Internal`. This managed to fix itself by running the program once, but I'd still like to know why this happened and how to fix this in other ways besides letting the program run.

Also, import statements like `import program.Internal` where something from within `src` is imported are no longer functional. Here, IntelliJ always says "Cannot resolve symbol [last argument], so e.g. when trying `import program.Internal` IntelliJ says "Cannot resolve symbol Internal".

What's weird is that, even tough it supposedly can't import these classes, using these classes still works perfectly fine when the program is run... Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: How exactly did you "move" your code? It smells like you copied some source files over but not the proper controls. With this directory layout, you should probably have imported it as a Maven (perhaps Gradle) project into your IDE.

Comment: It's already a gradle project. I moved it by copying the project folder to a USB, putting it in the laptop and then opening it there. So all files should still be there.

Comment: IntelliJ clearly doesn't correctly recognize your source root at `src/main/java`, so that's the problem. If your project is correctly organized, you should be able to remove it from IntelliJ and re-import it fresh from the `build.gradle`.

Comment: By remove do you mean close the project? And how do I re-import using the build.gradle file? So far I've only used it to make a build (I'm still pretty new to IntelliJ and programming in general)

Comment: If what you meant is reloading the gradle project, it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to run "File | Invalidate Caches". Also you may backup/remove IDE related data (.iml files and .idea folder) and reimport project selecting gradle.build file.